# Update error MongoDB - BSON field 'update.updates.u' is the wrong type 'array', expected type 'object'

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a script, but it stopped working and this error appeared: **BSON field 'update.updates.u' is the wrong type 'array', expected type 'object'**. what could be the problem?

```
db.getCollection('docs').update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      Orders: {
        $map: {
          input: "$Orders",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                "CustomFields": {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                    {
                      "Weight-test": "$$this.CustomFields.Weight"
                    },
                    "$$this.CustomFields"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "Orders.CustomFields.Weight"
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Comment: which server version?

Comment: Are any of the `"Orders"` elements arrays?  Are any `"Orders.CustomFields" arrays?

Comment: They are both arrays, but sometimes they can be null